# How to set Eclipse's output directory from Gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-eclipse

I am using Gradle's eclipse plugin. For cross-project reference reasons, I need Eclipse's output directory to not be the default `bin`, rather `ecbuild`.

Everytime I run `./gradlew eclipse`, it overwrites this output directory setting.

How to make sure it doesn't, or how to set it within gradle build script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to the `build.gradle` script:

```
eclipse {
   classpath { defaultOutputDir = file('ecbuild') }
}
```

This might require you to upgrade the version of your gradle wrapper.

If so, run :

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 3.3
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, seting defaultOutputDir was not enough. So I did the following:

```
eclipse {
     classpath {
        defaultOutputDir = file("build")
        file.whenMerged {
            entries.each { entry ->
                if (entry.kind == 'src' && entry.hasProperty('output')) {
                    entry.output = entry.output.replace('bin/', "build/")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```